# CSS bootstrap Dropdown menu is hidden by parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

How can I make the bootstrap drop down menu is overflow the parent div (blue behind), I've tried to set zindex for drop down menu class but not work.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0%;
  min-width: 170px;
  width:170px;

  z-index: 1000;
}
```

So I want the menu can be seen full as it is over the parent div not be hidden as in the image.

Comment: try to let the dropdown with `position:absolute` and the container with `position:relative`

Answer (score -1):

+try to set overflow:visible (on parent element)